# ObjectiveC/Cocoa Screencapture/Crosshead mouse pointer selector help

Tags: xcode, image, macos, upload

I want to write a basic app so I can upload some images to my personal server and as the CMD+Shift+4 Screen capture method apple offers doesn't let you upload your images I thought I would start from scratch... I've looked around quite a lot on how to make something what lets me grab a selection of my screen (like the crosshair apple offer) and can't find any samples/pointers however I've seen other tools such as [gyazo](http://gyazo.com) use the exact same capture system apple offer :S... Is it some sort of framework I can access in Xcode or something?

If anyone knows how its done I would be very grateful.

Thanks

Liam

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just run [`screencapture(1)`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/screencapture.1.html) and capture to a temporary file location which your app then reads.

Comment: Thanks... Looks like this will work well... for anyone who needs to know what to do.. use the 'system()' command to run the screencapture utility

Comment: spawning processes is no longer allowed by the osx sandboxing appstore requirements. :(

Comment: Nobody says you have to write an App Store app. :-)